# Bootstrap 3 scroll spy

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Hi I'm trying to get scroll spy working in my navigation but it's not
Here's a link to my site: http://www.saracook.coffeecup.com

Here's how I implemented it:

```
 <body class="body" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse collapse">
 <div class="main">
 <!--HOMEPAGE-->
 <section id="home_page">
 <div class="home_page">

<!--NAVBAR-->

   <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about_page">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio_page">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact_page">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems scrollspy works good, but there is some trouble with prettyPhoto() plugin. Maybe you forget to include javascript for this plugin on the page.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using pretty photo anymore so that shouldn't be there, thank you. So scroll spy is working for you? I can't see it on my computer

Comment: remove all js mistake and try to change `.navbar-collapse collapse`  in the data-target and in js to the `.navbar-collapse`